# Merge list of dfs AND extract index as a new column

Tags: r, dataframe, list

`library(tidyverse)`

I have this list of dfs:

```
my_list <-  list(structure(list(observations = c(1L, 5L), variables = c(4L, 
                                                                        8L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("asp_202003...Copy.xlsx", 
                                                                                                                  "asp_202003.xlsx")), structure(list(observations = c(3L, 1L), 
                                                                                                                                                      variables = 5:4), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("eay_201008_a.xlsx", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                            "eay_202003.xlsx")), structure(list(observations = 3:4, variables = c(4L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  6L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("wana_202309...Copy.xlsx", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            "wana_202309.xlsx")))
```

I merge the dfs like so:

```
my_merge <- my_list %>% reduce(full_join)
```

Output:
my_merge

```
#  observations variables
#1            1         4
#2            5         8
#3            3         5
#4            3         4
#5            4         6
```

But I would want to keep the index names (or extract them) in a new column called 'file', like so:

Desired output:

```
# file                      observations     variables
# asp_202003...Copy.xlsx               1             4
# asp_202003.xlsx                      5             8
# etc.
```

Also note, the desired output should have 6 rows, not 5 as in current my_merge object! In current my_merge object, identical values between two of the rows means one was 'lost'. This is also why I want to set file name as index.

Comment: Please add library(...) for the packages you're using.

Comment: @s_baldur I added `tidyverse`. Is this ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make them into tibbles first and save row names as a variable then use `bind_rows()`.

```r
library(dplyr)
my_list <-  list(structure(list(observations = c(1L, 5L), variables = c(4L, 8L)), class = "data.frame", 
                           row.names = c("asp_202003...Copy.xlsx", "asp_202003.xlsx")), 
                 structure(list(observations = c(3L, 1L), variables = 5:4), class = "data.frame", 
                           row.names = c("eay_201008_a.xlsx", "eay_202003.xlsx")), 
                 structure(list(observations = 3:4, variables = c(4L, 6L)), class = "data.frame", 
                           row.names = c("wana_202309...Copy.xlsx", "wana_202309.xlsx")))

bind_rows(purrr::map(my_list, ~as_tibble(.x, rownames="file")))
#> # A tibble: 6 × 3
#>   file                    observations variables
#>   <chr>                          <int>     <int>
#> 1 asp_202003...Copy.xlsx             1         4
#> 2 asp_202003.xlsx                    5         8
#> 3 eay_201008_a.xlsx                  3         5
#> 4 eay_202003.xlsx                    1         4
#> 5 wana_202309...Copy.xlsx            3         4
#> 6 wana_202309.xlsx                   4         6
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Would be more efficient and readable to manipulate the row.names after bind_rows(). `as_tibble(bind_rows(my_list), rownames = "file")`.

Answer (score 3):

You can `rownames_to_column` along with `rbind`, like below

```
library(tibble)

do.call(rbind, my_list) %>%
   rownames_to_column(var = "file")
```

or, if you prefer base R solutions, you can try

```
`row.names<-`(
   do.call(
      rbind,
      lapply(my_list, \(x) cbind(
         file = row.names(x),
         x
      ))
   ), NULL
)
```

which gives

```
                     file observations variables
1  asp_202003...Copy.xlsx            1         4
2         asp_202003.xlsx            5         8
3       eay_201008_a.xlsx            3         5
4         eay_202003.xlsx            1         4
5 wana_202309...Copy.xlsx            3         4
6        wana_202309.xlsx            4         6
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use base r and two lines of code:

```
my_list <-  list(structure(list(observations = c(1L, 5L), variables = c(4L, 
8L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("asp_202003...Copy.xlsx", 
"asp_202003.xlsx")), structure(list(observations = c(3L, 1L), 
variables = 5:4), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("eay_201008_a.xlsx", 
"eay_202003.xlsx")), structure(list(observations = 3:4, variables = c(4L, 
6L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("wana_202309...Copy.xlsx", 
                         "wana_202309.xlsx")))


mydf <- do.call( rbind, my_list) 
mydf$file <- row.names(mydf)
```

Comment: You can use do.call(rbind, ...) instead of Reduce here.

Comment: does `do.call` offer speed performance over `Reduce`?

Comment: Yes, especially if the list is long since it will only call rbind once instead of length(list)-1 times.

Answer (score 2):

A `purrr::list_rbind` solution:

```
my_merge <- rownames_to_column(list_rbind(my_list), "file")
```

Output:

```
> my_merge
                     file observations variables
1  asp_202003...Copy.xlsx            1         4
2         asp_202003.xlsx            5         8
3       eay_201008_a.xlsx            3         5
4         eay_202003.xlsx            1         4
5 wana_202309...Copy.xlsx            3         4
6        wana_202309.xlsx            4         6
```